# How to print the initials with awk

Tags: awk

I have this input text file:

```
Pedro Paulo da Silva
22 years old
Brazil

Bruce Mackenzie
30 years old
United States of America

Lee Dong In
26 years old
South Korea
```

The name of the person is always the first line of the file (and the first line after the empty line /n).

I have to do this output (ignoring everything except the names in the first lines):

```
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

Don't know how to do that with awk. I just know that awk 'print {$number}' will grab the column $number and that's how I'm supposed to grab their names.

I've searched here and found this: `sed -e 's/$/ /' -e 's/\([^ ]\)[^ ]* /\1/g' -e 's/^ *//'`
But I have to use awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v RS="" -F '\n' '                  # records are separated on blank lines by setting RS to null
{
    n = split($1, b, " ")               # split the name on spaces
    init = b[1]                         # the first name
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)            # loop over the remaining
        init = init substr(b[i], 1, 1)  # append the initial
    print init
}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

Comment: The first split to fill array `a[]` doesn't look necessary. You could add `-F '\n'` and directly operate on `$1`. Anyway, +1 for the comments.

Comment: @xhienne oh! that's right. Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat input
Pedro Paulo da Silva
22 years old
Brazil

Bruce Mackenzie
30 years old
United States of America

Lee Dong In
26 years old
South Korea
$ awk '!a{ printf "%s", $1; 
            for( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ ) printf("%c", $i); 
            printf "\n"; a=1}
        /^$/{a=0}' input
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following once.

```
awk '
!NF{
  count=0
  next
}
++count==1{
  printf("%s%s",$1,NF==1?ORS:"")
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    printf("%s%s",substr($i,1,1),i==NF?ORS:"")
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
!NF{                                ##Checking if line is empty then do following.
  count=0                           ##Setting count to 0 here.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
++count==1{                         ##Checking condition if count is 1 then do following.
  printf("%s%s",$1,NF==1?ORS:"")    ##Using printf to print $1 followed by new line OR nothing.
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){               ##Starting a for loop here.
    printf("%s%s",substr($i,1,1),i==NF?ORS:"") ##Using printf to print sub string of current line from field 2 to last field of line and printing only 1st character of line.
  }
}' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Pedro Paulo da Silva
22 years old
Brazil

Bruce Mackenzie
30 years old
United States of America

Lee Dong In
26 years old
South Korea
```

then

```
awk '{if(prevline==""){print gensub(/ ([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]+/, "\\1", "g")};prevline=$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

Explanation: there are two things to do, first select which lines to print, then change their content into initials. For first I check if previous line (`prevline`) is empty string, GNU `AWK` if variable was not set earlier treat it as empty string for comparison with another string, so condition is meet for first line, then after processing each line I set `prevline` to line content (`$0`) so in next turn it does hold previous line. For conversion into initials I harness [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function - I instruct AWK to replace space-letter-letters using letter and print such changed line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Mixing this with [tshiono's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67578212/7233423) based on `RS=""` and `FS='\n'` would lead to an interesting and concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {X = 1} NR == X{print $1 substr($2, 1, 1) substr($3, 1, 1) substr($4, 1, 1); X += 4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential option is:

```
awk '/[0-9]/{print p} {p=$1 substr($2, 1, 1) substr($3, 1, 1) substr($4, 1, 1) substr($5, 1, 1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation with a mix from the existing answers.

```
awk '{
  if (!x) {                      # Variable x is empty at the start or set to empty line
    res=$1                       # Set res to field 1
    for(i=2; i<=NF;i++) {        # Loop the rest of the fields starting at field 2
      res = res substr($i, 1, 1) # Concat the first char from each field with res
    }
    print res
  }
  x=$0                           # Set x variable to the value of the current line
}
' file
```

Output

```
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` in paragraph mode and using `gensub()` function you can get it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = ""; FS = "\n"} {print gensub(/([[:space:]])([[:alpha:]]{1})([^[:space:]+])+/,"\\2","g",$1)}' file
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another. It turned out a bit like @WilliamPursell's, though (++):

```
$ awk '!p{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf (i==1?"%s%s":"%c%s"),$i,(i==NF?ORS:"")}{p=NF}' file
```

Output:

```
PedroPdS
BruceM
LeeDI
```

"Explained":

```
$ awk '
!p {                                                   # if previous record empty
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                                 # process record for ...
        printf (i==1?"%s%s":"%c%s"),$i,(i==NF?ORS:"")  # ... output
}
{ p=NF }' file                                         # store field count
```